# OpenGL: Using glColorPointer make color weird

Tags: opengl

Like the picture showed in the link below. I want to color my robot hand with white color(RGB: 0.9 0.9 0.9). When I use glColor3f, the white color display correctly. But when I store RGB data in GLfloat array and call glColorPointer, the color becomes so weird.

Here is code of right arm

```
 static const GLfloat playerBodyColor[] = {0.9, 0.9, 0.9};

 glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
 //glColor3f(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
 glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, playerBodyColor);
 glTranslatef(0.0, player_body_height/6, player_body_width/2+LENGTH_UNIT/2);
 glRotatef(340.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
 glPushMatrix();
 glTranslatef(2*LENGTH_UNIT, 0.0, 0.0);
 glScalef (4.0, 1.0, 1.0);
 copyCodeSolidCube (LENGTH_UNIT);
 glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
 glPopMatrix();
```

If I change code like this:

```
 static const GLfloat playerBodyColor[] = {0.9, 0.9, 0.9};


 //glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
 glColor3f(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
 //glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, playerBodyColor);
 glTranslatef(0.0, player_body_height/6, player_body_width/2+LENGTH_UNIT/2);
 glRotatef(340.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
 glPushMatrix();
 glTranslatef(2*LENGTH_UNIT, 0.0, 0.0);
 glScalef (4.0, 1.0, 1.0);
 copyCodeSolidCube (LENGTH_UNIT);
 //glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
 glPopMatrix();
```

The color shows correct.

The picture of correct-color code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xknCC.jpg

The picture of wrong-color code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1SOc.jpg

In the code, I also called a function copyCodeSolidCube.
Here is part of copyCodeSolidCube code:

```
glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState (GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer (3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vert);
glNormalPointer (GL_FLOAT, 0, norm);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, one);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, two);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, three);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, four);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, five);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, six);

glDisableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState (GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: please show us the codes

Comment: Wait a minute. Let me paste my code. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `glColorPointer()`, you specify an array of colors, one for each vertex. For example, if your cube has 8 vertices, you need an array of 8 colors. Since you have 3 components per color, the total size of the array you need is 24 floats.

Or, since you currently have 4 vertices per draw call, you need 4 colors in the color array, for 4 * 3 = 12 float values.

The big advantage of using this is of course that you can color each vertex individually. If you really want the same color for each vertex, `glColor3f()` was actually the right call to use. Or you can use a slight variation:

```
glColor3fv(playerBodyColor);
```

This is equivalent to the `glColor3f()` call you had, except that it's more convenient if you already have the color in an array of 3 values.